# lower case calligraphic letters in mathdesign

Tags: fonts, mathdesign

I'd like to use lower case calligraphic letters in mathdesign. I can pull in the letters from dutchcal by undefining `mathcal` following `\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}` but then I use the prettier calligraphic characters from mathdesign.  Is there a convenient way to pull in only the (=all) lower case calligraphic letters from dutchcal?

Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}
\let\mathcal\undefined  % without this line I get an error message
\usepackage{dutchcal}  % without this line and the one before it, I don't get lower case calligraphic letters

\begin{document}

I want $\mathcal{F}$ from mathdesign, but mathdesign doesn't contain $\mathcal{f}$.  The only way I can get $\mathcal{f}$ from dutchcal to work is as indicated, but that gives me $\mathcal{F}$ from dutchcal.   The symbol $\mathfrak{l}$ is just too ugly compared to $\mathcal{l}$.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Do what `dutchcal` does, but defining a different command:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[charter]{mathdesign}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{dutchcal}{\skewchar\font=45 }
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}{<-> s*[1.0] dutchcal-r}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}{<-> s*[1.0] dutchcal-b}{}
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathlcal}{U}{dutchcal}{m}{n}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathlcal}{bold}{U}{dutchcal}{b}{n}



\begin{document}

\verb|$\mathcal{F}$|: $\mathcal{F}$ (mathdesign)

\verb|$\mathlcal{f}$|: $\mathlcal{f}$ (dutchcal)

\verb|$\mathlcal{F}$|: $\mathlcal{F}$ (dutchcal)

\verb|$\mathcal{F}\mathlcal{f}$|: $\mathcal{F}\mathlcal{f}$

$\mathlcal{abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwyz}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Phenomenal!!!!!